# Buscar tags XML

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma string, similar a um documento XML:

```xml
<lists>
   <list name='NOVOS' values='1'>
   <list name='OLDS' values='2'>
</lists>
```

O que preciso é varrer esse código, e criar um array com os nome da lista.

Ficando, por exemplo, o retorno dele: 0 -> NOVOS e 1 -> OLDS e assim por diante.

Tentei:

```
preg_match( '/name="([^"]*)"/i', $s, $lists_return );
```

As vezes funciona e as vezes retorna somente o primeiro item da lista. A variável `s` é onde esta a string que informei acima. Pode ser em expressão regular.

Comment: "similar a um document XML". É um xml ou não, por que no titulo está "Buscar tags XML", sendo assim, ficaria fácil ajudar.

Comment: Não é XML, é apenas uma string, no formato que indiquei. Se fosse XML poderia usar os varios exemplos, mas o formato é o citado na pergunta:

Comment: <lists>
      <list name='NOVOS' values='1'>
      <list name='OLDS' values='2'>
</lists>

Answer (score 0):

Tenta converter sua string em um xml.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; //elimina espaços em branco
$dom->formatOutput = false;
// carrega o xml 
$dom->loadXML($suaString, LIBXML_NOBLANKS | LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);

$dom->getElementsByTagName("tagQueVcQuerPegar")->item(0);
```

Ai vc pode fazer um for para iterar sobre os itens